# Comprehensive book to study about wireless technology

Tags: wifi

I am searching for a comprehensive book on wireless technology that covers in detail almost everything about wireless technology, including the related protocols, security, hacks, etc. I know it is not possible to cover this in a single book. Can you suggest a basic book to start with, and then books to go to the next level? I want to make my career in the field of wireless security.

Comment: Are you asking specifically for a book on wireless *security*, or *wireless in general*? If the latter, I'd recommend asking on superuser.com. Regardless, lists of books are borderline ontopic - will probably be made CW...

Comment: I think I require both.

Comment: as I said, here you can ask for *security* books. Btw, do you really mean "wireless", or did you actually mean more specifically "wifi"?

Comment: Here I mean wireless. I will start with wifi but I want to go for complete 802.11. The book suggested by lbwtz2 is good. I have started to read that. I will wait for further suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

Start with this: [Wireless Security Know it All](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1856175294)

Is focused on the security aspect but it also goes deep in many other theoretical topics, like protocols, signal theory etc.

Comment: The book alas doesn't dwell long on modulation; a satisfactory introductory text on general communications stuff would be John G. Proakis, Mahmoud Salehi, Digital Communications (5th ed., 2008). ISBN 9780072957167. YMMV